# Machine Learning: Picking hidden neurons based on sample data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have recently found [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136542) to a question regarding choosing a good neural network structure, specifically in regard to the hidden layers and their neurons. The answer gives a general formula that produces a non-optimal but good starting point for the network.

```
Nh = (Ns)/(a * (Ni + No))
```

Where:

```
Ni = number of input neurons.
No = number of output neurons.
Ns = number of samples in training data set.
a = an arbitrary scaling factor usually 2-10.
```

So what does this mean if I have 8 inputs, 8 outputs (regression mode), and a training set of 37 million examples? Plugging in the numbers with a scaling factor of 10 is over 230,000 hidden neurons, and reducing that scaling factor will only cause it to go up. Surely this is far too many?

For clarification, the training set is stock market candlestick data, and I am attempting to train the network to predict what the next candle might look like given the current one (and perhaps a few previous ones too). I plan on using backpropagation, which I know is very resource intensive, so surely I don't need hundreds of thousands of neurons in the hidden layers to make the network effective, would I?